# Как работает eventData в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно на `on('click')` элемента назначить некоторую функцию, описанную в другой части скрипта и передать в эту функцию параметр. Прочитал о том, что параметры в этом случае могут передаваться при помощи `eventData`, но никак не могу с ним разобраться. Что я делаю не так?

https://jsfiddle.net/0g8ckmyo/

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('span').on('click', {id: 'message'}, click);
```